# openpyxl dataframe filteration

Tags: python, dataframe, openpyxl

I'm just getting started with python and I need to get everything from column K into a list after filtering F and I columns with the respective values.

So basically when column F matches `stringA` and column I matches `stringC`, then save all values of column K to a list. I already have my code working for importing the correct modules, opening and saving the worksheet, I just need help on this piece.

I'm sure there is a different way to achieve it.

```py
l = []
for icol in sheet1.columns:
    coll = icol[0].column
    for cell in icol:
        if(coll == 'F' and cell.value == 'stringA' or coll == 'I' and cell.value == 'stringC'):
            print(coll, cell.value)
            if (coll == 'K'):
                l.append(cell.value)
print(l)
```

All I really need, is to specify the cell name in the append line. Perhaps there is a very pythonic way to do it. I'll share if I figure it out.

Comment: You say 'dataframe', but since you're not using `pandas`, I assume you meant 'worksheet'? Are you looking for answers that do use `pandas` or would you be opposed to answers that require it? (because it's pretty much trivial using `pandas` instead of `openpyxl`)

Comment: you should install `pandas`, then this would work. `df[(df['F']=='stringA') & (df['I']=='stringC')]['K'].tolist()`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I’m hoping to just stick with openpyxl to avoid importing multiple modules if not needed. 
Is there an example with openpyxl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `pandas`, `xlrd` and `openpyxl` all installed, this will work:

```
import pandas as pd

# this example data should result in a list with only 'value 1' and 'value 6'
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [None, None, None, None, None, 'stringA', None, None, 'stringC', None, 'value 1'],
    [None, None, None, None, None, 'stringX', None, None, 'stringC', None, 'value 2'],
    [None, None, None, None, None, 'stringA', None, None, 'stringX', None, 'value 3'],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None     , None, None, 'stringC', None, 'value 4'],
    [None, None, None, None, None, 'stringA', None, None, None     , None, 'value 5'],
    [None, None, None, None, None, 'stringA', None, None, 'stringC', None, 'value 6'],
])

# just writing the file, so you can verify it matches your input data
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', header=False, index=False)

# As @JiWei suggests, but using the column index instead of the name
print(df[(df[5] == 'stringA') & (df[8] == 'stringC')][10].tolist())
```

Result:

```
['value 1', 'value 6']
```

So, if you already have a file like `test.xlsx`, all you need is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=None)
print(df[(df[5] == 'stringA') & (df[8] == 'stringC')][10].tolist())
```